# Why does my Canon dSLR increase the ISO in Av mode?

Tags: canon, camera-settings

In Av mode with a Canon 7DII, trying to shoot stationary objects in low light, when I set the ISO to 100 and aperture at f/5.6 for DOF, I cannot stop the camera increasing the ISO significantly. I would have expected an extended shutter time (and hence use a tripod) but it seems to stick at 1/30 and increases the ISO.  Is it me?

Comment: Do you have safety shift enabled?

Comment: Are you sure it is 1/30 of a second (0.03333) ? Sounds like it should be 30 seconds.

Comment: what firmware are you using on your 7Dii?

Answer (score 2):

I've found this quirk on the 5D IV.

In Av mode, if the ISO is set to A, it still allows you to change the ISO via hardware buttons. But then when you release the shutter, it decides whatever ISO it wants.

Open the quick menu and make sure your ISO is set to a specific setting, not auto.

Comment: The OP says "I set the ISO to 100", so this doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: @Ph Did you set to ISO to 100 via hardware buttons or through the menu?

Comment: @PhilipKendall The point is you can set a specific ISO using the Hardware buttons or Quick Control screen and if "Auto ISO" is enabled in the menus the camera will still change it if it thinks it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

I took my 7DII and set it to Av, ISO 100 and f/5.6 and it worked as expected.

Either you camera body is malfunctioning, or you do not have the settings you think you have.